# Почему в переопределяемом (@Override) методе нельзя пробросить Exception?

Tags: java, исключения, override

Всем добрый вечер.

Столкнулся с интересной особенностью переопределяемых методов — исключения в них нельзя пробросить, только обработка внутри метода. Но почему? Хочется получить исчерпывающий ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: пробросить в смысле задекларировать `throws` в сигнатуре метода?

Comment: да. пробросить в смысле задекларировать в сигнатуре

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Есть два вида исключений в Java — checked и unchecked, подробнее можно почитать, например, в [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/company/golovachcourses/blog/225585/).

Checked исключения проверяются на этапе компиляции приложения, и должны где-то отлавливаться (catch), а методы, которые выбрасывают такие исключения, должны иметь в сигнатуре тип исключения, который может быть выброшен (напр. `void method() throws Exception`). При переопределении (@Override) метода, в сигнатуре которого не указан throws, нельзя бросить checked-исключение, потому что компилятор не сможет его отследить. Нерабочий пример:

```
class A {
    void foo() {}
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    void foo() throws Exception {}
}

A obj = new B(); 
obj.foo(); // Компилятор рассматривает obj как A, в котором нет throws, и не знает о том, что он бросает checked-исключение
```

Вы можете бросить unchecked-исключение, на основе RuntimeException или Error, без добавления throws в сигнатуру перезагруженного метода. Конечно, если вам не нужно именно checked-исключение.

Answer (score 9):

Можно, если переопределяемый метод суперкласса объявлен, как выбрасывающий тот же тип исключений или базовый к нему. Это один из основных принципов ООП - [LSP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Базовый к нему Вы имели в виду superclass?

Comment: Да, это и имею ввиду.